# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener not receiving events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Testing",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-min-3.4.1.js",
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Here's what I've got in my content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(`message received, ${request}`)
    }
);
```

Here's what I've got in my background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    console.log('on clicked')
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        console.log(activeTab);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { "message": "clicked_browser_action" });
    });
});
```

When I click my browser action, I do see the 'on clicked' logged, and the active tab logged, but I don't get the 'message received' log. Not sure what's going on here

Comment: Try to add tabs permission in your manifest.

Comment: An instance of the content script runs in each matching page so you should look in the tab's devtools, not in the background script devtools.

Comment: @V.Sambor I already have that

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked the tab's devtools, nothing gets logged

Comment: It means there's no content script running in that tab or you entered a filter on devtools console toolbar that hides the message. Make sure you've reloaded both the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab. On  success you will see the extension name in tab's console toolbar context switcher as well as in the Sources panel's content scripts sub-tab. P.S. In corporate network some URLs may be blocked by the admin, check chrome://policy